# Can't plot the graph correctly after trying to average out my values for each key in dictionary

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've tried to average out the values in my keys and put them into a list. However, when I tried to put the values into a graph, it just gives me lots of errors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

academic = {"Jane": [75, 80, 85, 60],
            "John": [60, 68, 74, 80],
            "Jerome": [81, 63, 77, 50],
            "Jason": [55, 76, 67, 60],
            "Jessica": [62, 45, 68, 55],
            "Joanne": [52, 47, 51, 70]}
for result in academic:
    average = round((academic[result][0]+academic[result][1]+academic[result][2]+academic[result][3])/4)
    academic[result] = average
    y = np.arange(len(academic))
    x = list(academic.values())
    plt.bar(x, y)
    plt.bar(x, y, align='center')
    plt.xticks(x, academic)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: You indent is broken, unindent `y = np.arange(len(academic))` and everything after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation is off, like Stephen Rauch says, but I think you also mixed `x` and `y` up. Switching them around makes more sense to me.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

academic = {"Jane": [75, 80, 85, 60],
            "John": [60, 68, 74, 80],
            "Jerome": [81, 63, 77, 50],
            "Jason": [55, 76, 67, 60],
            "Jessica": [62, 45, 68, 55],
            "Joanne": [52, 47, 51, 70]}
for result in academic:
    average = round((academic[result][0]+academic[result][1]+academic[result][2]+academic[result][3])/4)
    academic[result] = average
x = np.arange(len(academic))
y = list(academic.values())
plt.bar(x, y, align='center')
plt.xticks(x, academic)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Why do you have plt.bar twice?

Comment: Correct, not necessary. I just copied the rest from the question.